# Why is the suggested edits queue empty when I have suggested edits pending?

Tags: bug, review-queues, suggested-edits

I have two suggested edits waiting for review. Here is a screenshot of one of them:

[image: Your edit is pending review]

However, on the [review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review), it says that the suggested edits review queue is empty:

[image: 0 suggested edits]

I know that this isn't true since I have two of my own edits pending. How is this possible?

The reason why it's like this isn't because I don't have the privileges to review this queue. This is a screenshot taken at another time when I still don't have the privileges:

[image: 43 suggested edits]

Comment: Probably just caching. It might be that it is because you don't yet have edit review privileges though. Has it ever shown you another value?

Comment: @S.L.Barth Yes it usually shows another value. I've noticed this too and thought caching. (It says 1 is in the queue at the moment).

Comment: @S.L.Barth: I just tested with a low-rep smelly soc^Wtest account and saw the suggested edit count change on reloads. The OP just caught it at zero. I do think the counter hides your own posts out in review.

Comment: Since I'm not 100% certain about the implementation details, I've removed the status tag again. It *could* be there is an in-memory cache that perhaps has lost track of the count and thus *some* pages served show 0 suggested edits when that number is too far off the real number (reloads show it *sometimes* go to 0).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a lot of caching involved with that number. It should not be taken as an absolute. There are too many fast-moving numbers involved for that number to ever be exactly accurate.

That said, the occasional 0 for suggested edits on the page does look out of touch; the number is more frequently displayed as anywhing between 25 and 50 right now, so there *may* be an in-memory cache on one of the machines in the cluster that got a little lost.